# Ansible quoted heredoc in expect/command block not finding delimiter / multiline command in expect command

Tags: bash, ansible, escaping, heredoc

I'm trying to generate a script to be copied in an `ansible` expect/response block with `ssh` to the remote host. I'd like to avoid writing intermediate files.

I have two issues:

1. Ansible seems to do some processing in `command` which messes up multiline `bash` scripts, but I can get around it with `/bin/bash -c 'my \ multi \ line \ command'` (on actual multiple lines)
2. I can't seem to quote the EOF mark for the heredoc correctly **within** the `bash` invocation (see below)

```yaml
  - name: Generate script on the fly
    expect: 
      command: |
        /bin/bash -c 'ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -p {{ ansible_ssh_port }} {{ ansible_user }}@{{ ansible_host }} "cat - > {{ tgtdir }}/myscript.sh" <<-'EOF' 
          #! /bin/env sh
          a="/$0"; a=${a%/*}; a=${a#/}; a=${a:-.}; THIS=$(cd "$a"; pwd)
          echo "Script dir == ${THIS}"
          echo "{{ someansiblevar }}"
          EOF
        '
      responses:
        (.*)password: "{{ ansible_ssh_pass }}"
    delegate_to: localhost
```

(Note that in this example I'm apparently getting away with using single quotes within single quotes, but other variations all fail as well.)

I have tried to escape the quotes around the first `EOF` in different ways, but I always get the warning:

```
"stdout_lines": ["/bin/bash: line 10: warning: here-document at line 0 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')", "", "admin@192.168.1.111's password: "]
```

And the contents of `myscript.sh` are either not correctly left alone (i.e. all `$...` expanded), or contain the last `EOF` (since it is not recognized as delimiter and is just reading to the end of the command block, hence the warning.

What is the correct way of handling this?

(Note that I delegate to `localhost` because I don't want to rely on `python` on the target host, these are minimal systems with only `ssh`).

Comment: Make sure the indentation on the `EOF` line is only TAB characters, not spaces.

Comment: That was quick ;) Unfortunately this gives: `Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  found a tab character where an indentation space is expected`

Comment: If YAML doesn't allow tabs, you can't use an indented `EOF` token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the closing EOF left by two spaces. At the moment it does not start at the beginning of its line, so bash won't see it as a delimiter.

From the bash man-page:

> Here Documents
>
> This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the
> current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no
> trailing blanks) is seen. All of the lines read up to that point are
> then used as the standard input for a command. The format of
> here-documents is:
>
> ```
> <<[-]word
>         here-document 
> delimiter
> ```
>
> No parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed
> on `word`. If any characters in `word` are quoted, the `delimiter` is the
> result of quote removal on `word`, and the lines in the here-document
> are not expanded. If `word` is unquoted, all lines of the here-document
> are subjected to parameter expansion, command substitution, and
> arithmetic expansion. In the latter case, the character sequence
> \<newline> is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters \,
> $, and `. If the redirection operator is `<<-`, then all leading tab
> characters are stripped from input lines and the line containing
> `delimiter`. This allows here-documents within shell scripts to be
> indented in a natural fashion.

So you'll either need to remove the indentation from the `EOF` line or indent everything with TABs instead of spaces. I suggest that the former option is simpler.

Comment: The "two spaces outdent" combined with double quotes (i.e. `<<-"EOF"`) did the trick! (Single quotes where recognized as delimiter, but the heredoc was inadvertently parsed.) Thanks!

Comment: While we're at it: is there a way to do multi-line in `command: |` without needing the extra `bash` invocation?

Comment: I suspect that using single quotes might have been lost because your whole string was inside single quotes, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: You could write your shell script on a single line (separating commands with `;`), though that would probably just mean that you would drop the `bash` at the start of the command and put it in as the argument to `ssh`.